# OneDrive API download in parts

Tags: java, onedrive

I am currently trying to develop a Java based app to access OneDrive.

Today i tried to implement the download as described here: https://dev.onedrive.com/items/download.htm

I wanted to use the *range* parameter, to offer the user the capability to pause large downloads. But no matter how i send the parameter be at within the HTTP-Request header or in the URL as a GET-Parameter it will always send me the complete file.

Things i tried so far:

1. > https:/ /api.onedrive.com/v1.0/drive/items/***/content?range=0-8388607

(OAuth via HTTP header)

2. > https:/ /api.onedrive.com/v1.0/drive/items/***/content:

   Header: Authorization: ***

   range: 0-8388607
3. > https:/ /api.onedrive.com/v1.0/drive/items/***/content:

   Header: Authorization: ***

   range: bytes=0-8388607

I also tried Content-Range and various variations on lower and upper case without success. Any reason why this dose not work?

PS.:

The links a broken because i am using a new account that only allows 2 links per post, I am aware that ther is a space between the two // in my post ;)

Answer (score 2):

Requesting the range of the file is supported.  You might want to use fiddler or some other tool to see if the original headers are being passed after the 302 redirect is performed.  Below are the HTTP requests and responses when I provide the range header which is being passed on after the 302 redirect occurs.  You'll notice that a HTTP 206 partial content response is returned. Additionally, to resume a download, you can use "Range: bytes=1025-" or whatever the last byte received was.  I hope that helps.

`GET https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/drive/items/item-id/content HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Bearer 
Range: bytes=0-1024
Host: api.onedrive.com`

`HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Content-Length: 0
Location: https://kplnyq.dm2302.livefilestore.com/edited_location
Other headers removed`

`GET https://kplnyq.dm2302.livefilestore.com/edited_location
Range: bytes=0-1024
Host: kplnyq.dm2302.livefilestore.com`


`HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
Cache-Control: public
Content-Length: 1025
Content-Type: audio/mpeg
Content-Location: https://kplnyq.dm2302.livefilestore.com/edited_location
Content-Range: bytes 0-1024/4842585
Expires: Tue, 11 Aug 2015 21:34:52 GMT
Last-Modified: Mon, 12 Dec 2011 21:33:41 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
Other headers removed`